# How to save a raster and vector into a single PNG file in GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, vector, png

I am trying to save a raster and vector into a PNG file. The vector is overlayed on top of the raster map. I was only able to save the raster file into a png using r.out.png but without the vector.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
d.mon start=png
d.rast RASTER
d.vect VECTOR
d.mon stop=png
```

**This will basically render VECTOR layer on top RASTER layer to a file called** `map.png`.

Other things you could do with `d.mon start=png` - `d.mon stop=png`:

- Type `d.erase` to wipe the slate clean before committing with `d.mon stop=png`
- Include the legend with `d.rast.leg`:

  ```
  d.mon start=png
  d.rast.leg RASTER
  d.vect VECTOR
  d.mon stop=png
  ```
- Put the legend to a separate image with `d.legend`:

  ```
  d.mon start=png
  d.legend RASTER
  d.mon stop=png
  ```

Useful stuff..

Answer (score 4):

Compose your map and export using `d.out.file` http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/html_grass64/d.out.file.html

Comment: d.out.file did not work. It displays "Command 'd.out.file' not yet implemented in the GUI. Try adding it as a command layer instead."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is going to depend on what software you're using.

Also, I think that in saving them as a .png, you're going to be losing any distinction between the two, as far as being able to use them separately.

Anyways, in the case that you're using Arcgis, you should be able to go:

File --> Export Map, where you can save your current view as a .png.

Comment: I'm using GRASS. I'm finding a script that would make it work instead of using the save option in the interface

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `ps.map`[1](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/ps.map.html) to export vectors and the raster to a *.ps. Then just convert the *.ps into *.png (`convert out.ps out.png`)

Comment: I cannot convert the .ps to .png. I tried `# convert to PNG
pstoimg -antialias -aaliastext -out flood_warning.png -scale 1.3 \
  -crop tb flood_warning.ps` but it does not work. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: What happened.. the error message?

Comment: It displays: `ERROR: pstoimg : illegal request`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, I guess. Display the desired layers to elaborate your map and simply make a screenshot. Then, save as png.